# How print error or warning messages in the main document with LaTeX without using TeX code?

Tags: errors, warnings

I simply want to print out some warning and error messages in some cases. I only find solutions using TeX-code (`makeatletter`...) or inside package code (`\PackageError`). For the latter one I wasn't able to find a documentation.

Is there another solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{A} }
    {A case}
    {%
        \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{B} }
        {B case}
        {%
            \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{C} }
            {C case}
            {%
                % print out error message that
                % only A, B or C are allowed
                % values
            }
        }

    }
}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{X} % error
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want `\errmessage{only A, B or C are allowed}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{A} }%
    {A case}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{B} }%%%
        {B case}%%%
        {%
            \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{C} }%%%
            {C case}%%%
            {%
               \GenericError{[mycode] }{Bad input}%
                            {[mycode] Only A B or C\MessageBreak allowed}%
                            {read the doc}%%%
            }%%
        }%%
%%
    }%%
}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{X} % error
\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Bad input.

[mycode] Only A B or C
[mycode] allowed
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.27 \mymacro{X}
                 % error
? h
read the doc
?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `expl3` (that you already load along with `fontspec`). Case switching is simpler and also defining error messages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {A}{\mymacroA}
    {B}{\mymacroB}
    {C}{\mymacroC}
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { buhtz/mymacro } { wrong-value } { #1 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { buhtz/mymacro } { wrong-value }
 {
  Bad~value~'#1'
 }
 {
  You~can~only~use~A,~B~or~C,~you~had~#1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mymacroA}{Typed A}
\newcommand{\mymacroB}{Typed B}
\newcommand{\mymacroC}{Typed C}


\begin{document}

\mymacro{A}

\mymacro{B}

\mymacro{C}

\mymacro{X} % error

\end{document}
```

Here's the relevant part of an interactive session

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! buhtz/mymacro error: "wrong-value"
! 
! Bad value 'X'
! 
! See the buhtz/mymacro documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.44 \mymacro{X}
                 % error
? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| You can only use A, B or C, you had X
|...............................................
?
```

Note that error message management is split into two parts: in the macro we *use* a predefined error message, calling it by “module” and “name”. Up to four arguments are allowed in the definition.

Avoid loading `xltxtra` (which used to be recommended some time ago, but now provides no essential feature); just load `fontspec`.

Comment: Why should I avaoid loading xltxtra? I see no reason why I shouldn't.

Comment: @buhtz When your commands `\textsuperscript` or `\textsubscript` will do funny things, you'll know why I recommend avoiding `xltxtra`.

Comment: I don't know these commands. ;)